# Different timer intervals with lots of timer instances

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make an trading bot but exchange has a restriction like this. If you trade anything, you have to wait 5 seconds. If you didnt trade on last 5 seconds, no restriction. If I trade 2 seconds ago, I need to wait 3 seconds for this trade and if I want to trade again same time, This trade should wait 8 seconds. But the problem is, If my algorithm want to trade lots of trade same time, e.g timer is waiting 5 seconds and trying to buy or sell all waiting trades same time in that timer.Elapsedin this code snippet.

```
    public static Stopwatch checkOrder(Stopwatch stopwatch)
    {
            if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 5000)
            {
                stopwatch.Restart();
                Trade(stopwatch);
                return stopwatch;
            }
            else
            {

                System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer()
                {
                    AutoReset = false,
                    Interval = 5000 - stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
                };

                timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
                {
                    stopwatch.Restart();
                    Trade(stopwatch);
                };
                timer.Start();
            }
}
```

I tried also Thread.Sleep but I need most effective way as performance. Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

I am using stopwatch to calculate 5 seconds and resetting stopwatch after every trade.

**UPDATE 2**

**What I get**

**1. Buy order Sent**

```
{"success":true}

//2 second later want to new trade
//in this point, function should wait 3 seconds more to send this order.
```

**2. Buy order Sent**

```
{"success":false,"message":"Wait at least 5 second for new trade"}

// 1 second later
//in this point, function should wait 7 seconds more to send this order.
```

**3. Buy order Sent**

```
{"success":false,"message":"Wait at least 5 second for new trade"}

// 3 second later
//in this point, function should wait 9 seconds more to send this order.
```

**Expected Output**

**1. Buy order Sent**

```
{"success":true}

//2 second later want to new trade

timer (3000)
```

**2. Buy order Sent**

```
{"success":true}

// 1 second later

timer (7000)
```

**3. Buy order Sent**

```
{"success":true}

// 3 second later

timer (9000)
```

Comment: Have you considered one more than one timer?

Comment: Yeah but I could not make it too @mjwills , Timer wasnt ending, only increased timer interval.

Comment: "all waiting trades same time in that timer.Elapsedin" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: Im not sure how to describe, trying to buy or sell. You can check again @HansPassant,,  Trying to buy First, second and third trade same time

Comment: I don't understand the problem either? You describe that you can only execute a second trade if 5 seconds have past from the previous trade? Just create a timer with a 5 second interval and then execute the trade until you stop the timer?!

Comment: You didn't fix the mysterious phrase.  Odds you'll get ahead with this approach are low.  Instead, make sure you can properly parse the server's error response.  When you get it, *then* delay for a while.

Comment: A single timer and a queue sorted by next execution time is a good way to handle this; you can sleep until the first item is ready (cancel sleep if a new item is queued), execute first item and insert if back into the queue at the appropriate time. If you persist the queue in a database you can even restart your app and carry on at the right point.

Comment: @HansPassant I hope this is more clear with this example.

Comment: @Tomek Can you check again ? I tried to explain better.

Comment: @IanMercer Thanks for the idea, I tried lots of things. I will also try to this.Is there any source code for this idea to help me. Im kind of newbie on .net for this.

Comment: @mnnavc Question has been closed so I can't post an answer but take a look at `  SortedList<Item, DateTimeOffset>`, or any other priority queue implementation, insert items into it with next run time, peek first item, delay until now is that time, consume it and repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that for this task a queue and only one thread per execution is more suitable.
You don't need to create all these timers because you can still only perform one operation per unit of time.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var trade = new TradeService<TradeAction>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        trade.Trade(new TradeAction(j));
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
public interface ITradeAction
{
    void Execute();
}

public class TradeAction: ITradeAction
{
    private readonly int _i;

    public TradeAction(int i)
    {
        _i = i;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Test {_i}");
        Thread.Sleep(_i*1000);
    }
}

public sealed class TradeService<T> : IDisposable where T: ITradeAction
{
    private readonly int _waitInterval;
    private Stopwatch _stopwatch;
    private readonly object _sync = new object();
    private Queue<T> _queue;
    private Task _task;
    private bool _isRun;
    public TradeService(int waitInterval = 5000)
    {
        _waitInterval = waitInterval;
        _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        _queue = new Queue<T>();
        _isRun = true;
        _stopwatch.Start();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(Process);

    }

    public void Trade(T item)
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(item);
        }
        

    }

    private void Process()
    {
        while (_isRun)
        {
            if (_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < _waitInterval)
            {
                ;// nop
                continue;
            }
            _stopwatch.Reset();
            T item;
            lock (_sync)
            {
                item = _queue.Dequeue();
            }

            if (item != null)
            {
                item.Execute();
                _stopwatch.Start();
            }


        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_isRun)
        {
            _isRun = false;
            _task?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Queue is logical for it, I noticed yet but When I run your code, its doing nothing.Ends constatntly. What is the problem ?

Comment: Add Console.ReadLine(); to the method main

Comment: This is because the main thread is terminating, and the asynchronous handler has not yet had time to process any commands from the queue